# Django Queryset method .delete() not working

Tags: python, django, postgresql, transactions, tastypie

**Correction:** I've said the deletion doesn't work at all. That's wrong. It works most of times, for the same objects/records. It is just unstable: a few hundreds out of thousands of calls don't delete, despite there is no errors at all.

So, this gonna be a very weird question, look at this case:

```
if 'locations' in bundle.data:
    bundle.obj.locations.all().delete()
    for i, loc in enumerate(bundle.data['locations'], start=1):
        loc['order'] = i
        bundle.obj.locations.create(**loc)
```

The second line just doesn't work. No errors, just no deletion at all. Then I tried this instead:

```
if 'locations' in bundle.data:
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM bookings_bookinglocation WHERE booking_id='%s'" % bundle.obj.pk)
    connection.commit()
    for i, loc in enumerate(bundle.data['locations'], start=1):
        # ...
```

That above works better, but still frequently ignores the deletion.

I know it is ignoring because in my many tests I had the attention enough to check for the IDs before and after the .delete() call and they are the same, as below:

```
if 'locations' in bundle.data:
    ids_before = bundle.obj.locations.values("id")
    bundle.obj.locations.all().delete()
    ids_after = bundle.obj.locations.values("id")
    # ...
```

**Config:**

- Django 1.6.5 (tried with 1.6.1 too)
- Postgres 9.3
- **ATOMIC_REQUESTS** is True
- That is ran in **save** method in **django-tastypie**'s ModelResource.
- I tried with and without **@transaction.non_atomic_requests**
- There's neither dependency on that table nor error is showing when I call the .delete()
- It's not delaying the deletion for the end of transaction. I've checked that

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually verify this with the DB? because:

`Issues an SQL DELETE for the object. This only deletes the object in the database; the Python instance will still exist and will still have data in its fields.`

For more details, including how to delete objects in bulk, see Deleting objects.

If you want customized deletion behavior, you can override the delete() method. See Overriding predefined model methods for more details.`

Comment: I am aware of it, but it doesn't delete in DB's level (I've checked directly into DB). The example I gave above for "before_ids" and "after_ids", I tried also with ModelClass.objects.filter(...) which shouldn't return any cached object.

Comment: I suppose from the looks that locations is a foreign key? Are you using on_delete on the model?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: I am not using on_delete, but as I am deleting* the item (Booking's location) not the parent (Booking), on_delete shouldn't apply, right? As far as I know on_delete is to set the action for the item with the parent is deleted.